# Does performing a statistical analysis for a biologist warrant authorship?

Tags: authorship, statistics

I have a question, regarding authorship in a publication.

A colleague of mine who is a biologist (from a different group) received the second revision of her/his paper and in the revision it's been asked to do Anova in order to illustrate the significant change between 4 groups.

I'm saying a colleague not a friend! and also they may come more and more in the future.

I don't want to sound like a cheeky person, but have no idea whether if I do it I should be included in the paper or I should just do it as if I'm doing it for a so called friend! 
Should I be at least included in the acknowledgement, or?

I have no access to my boss to consult this with him. I would appreciate your help to make this point clear to me.

Thanks!

Comment: No, the other one is about statistical consultant. I have to do analysis although small one. but they have no clue about Anova, just the reviewer asked for it.

Comment: but thanks anyway, it was a helpful comment!

Comment: You are acting as a statistical consultant for your friend. Your motivations (being paid for it, or doing out of kindness towards your friend) are, in my opinion, irrelevant when deciding authorship.

Comment: Ok, you are right, then I do it for my friend.

Comment: What is relevant is the importance of the *creative* work that went into the paper. Just doing an ANOVA analysis of existing data isn't, helping to design the experiments and analysing the results *might* be. In any case, we here aren't privy to the detailed knowledge of your contribution to say one way or the other, that is up to the main author(s) to decide.